Duda con bucles for en Java
Estoy aprendiendo Java, acabamos de dar los array. Haciendo un ejercicio de práctica que me pide hallar la String más larga en un array de Strings. Me funciona perfectamente pero en un principio puse el bucle for como suelo hacerlo:
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)

Y VS Code me lo ha cambiado por lo siguiente:
for (String cadena1 : cadena) {

Eso es una ternaria? Quizá aún no lo he visto en el curso, ha sido vs code el que me dio la opción de cambiarlo y lo hice.
Dejo aquí el código del método completo en cuestión, cualquier consejo se agradece!
static String cadenaMasLarga(String[] cadena) { // metodo devuelve una String , pidiendo una array de Strings.
    String palabraMax = ""; // aquí vamos guardando la palabra que sea más larga en cada vuelta

    for (String cadena1 : cadena) {
        if (cadena1.length() > palabraMax.length()) { // compara cada palabra del array con la anterior en cada pasada
            palabraMax = cadena1;  // si la nueva palabra es más larga , la asigna a palabraMax
        }
    }
    return palabraMax;
}


a ello se le denomina bucle for each , se podria decir que es una manera mas rapida para recorrer arrays ,dependiendo del uso que requieras darle podes hacer uso del bucle tradicional o el for each,mas adelante descubriras otras formas de recorrer arrays como el uso de lambdas ,etc

String[] cadena es un arreglo de cadenas. Llamemos las cosas apropiadamente para evitar confusiones. Mí recomendación es que cambies el nombre del parámetro. Por ejemplo, a "palabras", "oraciones".

El primer for es el de toda la vida:
for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++)

Mientras que el segundo es un For Each (o For Mejorado según la especificación del lenguaje) y tiene esa pinta:
for (char caracter : cadena)

La expresión a la derecha de los dos puntos tiene que ser un arreglo o un Iterable.
Las principales ventajas son que el código es más compacto y no necesitas un índice para recorrer el arreglo/iterable.
El for mejorado en realidad es azúcar sintáctico y el compilador lo traduce a su equivalente con el for tradicional.
Para comparar, el operador ternario es azúcar sintáctico de if-else y se ve así:
int abs = x > 0 ? x : -x;


El segundo modo se llama For-Each Loop (bucle For-Each) y fue introducido en Java 1.5 por varios motivos, explicados en el mismo documento introductorio.

Una sintaxis más limpia y más elegante
Iterar sobre una colección es más feo de lo que debería ser. Considera el siguiente método, que toma una colección de tareas del temporizador y las cancela:
void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> c) {
    for (Iterator<TimerTask> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
        i.next().cancel();
}

El iterador es simplemente un desorden.

Reducir el riesgo de errores, facilitar la programación, flexibilidad
Además, la sintaxis anterior es una oportunidad para el error. La variable iterator aparece tres veces en cada bucle: es decir, dos oportunidades para equivocarse. La construcción for-each elimina el desorden y la oportunidad de error. Así es como se ve el ejemplo con la construcción for-each:
void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> c) {
    for (TimerTask t : c)
    t.cancel();
}

Cuando veas los dos puntos (:), léelo como "in". El bucle anterior se lee como "para cada TimerTask t en c". Como puedes ver, la construcción for-each combina perfectamente con los genéricos. Conserva toda la seguridad de tipos, mientras elimina el desorden restante. Como no tienes que declarar el iterador, no tienes que proporcionar una declaración genérica para él. (El compilador hace esto por ti, no necesitas preocuparse por ello).

Mejorar la iteración anidada
A continuación, se muestra un error común que la gente comete cuando intenta realizar una iteración anidada sobre dos colecciones:
List suits = ...;
List ranks = ...;
List sortedDeck = new ArrayList();

// ERROR - ¡lanza NoSuchElementException!
for (Iterator i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
    for (Iterator j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
        sortedDeck.add(new Card(i.next(), j.next()));
}

¿Puedes detectar el error? No te sientas mal si no puedes. Muchos programadores expertos han cometido este error en algún momento u otro. El problema es que el método next se llama demasiadas veces en la colección "externa" (suits). Se llama en el bucle interno tanto para la colección externa como para la interna, lo cual es incorrecto. Para solucionarlo, debes agregar una variable en el ámbito del bucle externo para almacenar el suit:
// Corregido, aunque un poco feo
for (Iterator i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Suit suit = (Suit) i.next();
    for (Iterator j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
        sortedDeck.add(new Card(suit, j.next()));
}

Entonces, ¿qué tiene que ver todo esto con la construcción for-each? ¡Está hecha a medida para la iteración anidada! Deleita tus ojos:
for (Suit suit : suits)
    for (Rank rank : ranks)
        sortedDeck.add(new Card(suit, rank));

La construcción for-each también se aplica a matrices, donde oculta la variable de índice en lugar del iterador. El siguiente método devuelve la suma de los valores en una matriz int:
// Devuelve la suma de los elementos de a
int sum(int[] a) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i : a)
        result += i;
    return result;
}



Por estos motivos, desde Java 1.5 es recomendable usar el bucle for-each siempre que sea posible y muchos IDEs sugieren el reemplazo, como ha sido el caso en el código que expones.
De hecho, la documentación así lo afirma:

Entonces, ¿cuándo debería usar el bucle for-each? Siempre que pueda.
Realmente embellece su código.

Limitaciones
Desafortunadamente, no puedes usar for-each en los siguientes casos.

Para filtrar datos
Considera, por ejemplo, el método expurgate.
// Removes the 4-letter words from c
static void expurgate(Collection<String> c) {
    for (Iterator<String> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
      if (i.next().length() == 4)
        i.remove();
}

El programa necesita acceso al iterador para eliminar el elemento actual. El bucle for-each oculta el iterador, por lo que no puedes llamar a remove. Por lo tanto, el bucle for-each no se puede usar para filtrar.

No se puede usar en bucles en los que se deben reemplazar elementos de una lista o matriz a medida que se recorre.

Por último, no se puede utilizar en bucles que deben iterar sobre varias colecciones en paralelo.


Los diseñadores conocían estas deficiencias, por lo que tomaron la decisión consciente de optar por una construcción limpia y simple que cubriera la gran mayoría de los casos.
Otros enlaces

La propuesta en JSR de introducir For-Each y los motivos que lo justificaban.

El aviso como nueva características a partir de Java 1.5 (Java 5).



Maestro, me saco el sombrero, ante tan buena respuesta, aunque me parece un poco desafortunada la referencia a Iterator, ya que es una forma que ha caido en desuso, a manos del for común, que es mucho más limpio.
